# Java-ajax cross site empty response string

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, cross-site

I am doing a cross-site ajax to java data transaction(Not sure if I named that correctly, so please forgive me about that). Part of code in Java file:

```
BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionsocket.
            getInputStream()));
DataOutputStream output =
            new DataOutputStream(connectionsocket.getOutputStream());
...
output.writeChars("some random text");
output.close();
```

Also I have index.php file with some jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $("#send_data").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'text',
                url: 'http://localhost:1024/'+$("#command").val(),
                success: function(data) {console.log(data);},
            error: function() { console.log("Error"); }
        })
    });
});
```

The command is sent correctly and received in Java side correctly. Then the request from java to ajax is *200 OK* too. The output is also working. (*For example if I remove output.close(), I do see in the firebug, that it is waiting for the output to be closed.*)

The only problem is, no matter what I do I get no response text. It's always an empty string :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cross-site ajax to java data transaction
```

and

```
index.php
```

and

```
Java
```

Implies you are violating [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You *must* use same `host:port` combination to retrieve the webpage (or at least the javascript version of the code that does AJAX) and send AJAX requests.

In other words, if your JS comes from `localhost:80` and you are trying to send AJAX request to `localhost:1024`, you are violating security policies.

There are ways to do cross-domain AJAX like [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), but do you *really* need that? I would suggest serving jQuery code from the servlet, or eliminate PHP at all, or, even better, rewrite everything in Scala or Erlang. :)

Comment: Then why the step one of Ajax->Java transfer is successful(Java end receives url sent), but step two fails? I assume if I am violating same origin policy, it should fail on step one. Can you explain that?

Comment: At which stage blocking should be depends on the browser. If you tried with old enough IE version (say 7 or 8), it *should* work (but no guarantees).

Comment: Why don't you just [test1](http://www.webdevout.net/test?0K) [test2](http://pastehtml.com/view/brs1b9um2.html) it? Enjoy firebugging the given links. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Both are inaccessible from my pc, but the second one is accessible from http://pastehtml.com/view/brs1b9um2.html. I have a feeling it has to do something with my settings in xampp?

Comment: No, it's your design. You are **not complying** to the same origin policy. It's just impossible what you are trying to.

Answer (score 1):

in your code you create `dataType:"xml"`
try to use with `text`.because in your response i don't see the xml format,you're create response with format text.

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'text',
                url: 'http://localhost:1024/'+$("#command").val(),
                success: function(data) {console.log(data);},
            error: function() { console.log("Error"); }
```

read this for option ajax request http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Yes yes sorry, really sorry, it was just I was desperately trying anything I could think of. I did try "text" for 99% of time, but stupid me writes xml in the question :( Really sorry. I edited that.

Comment: np ^^, how about your problem still not fix?

Comment: did you try to set response.setContentType("text/html"); ?

Comment: do you mean to write it in Java or Ajax? Cannot find this function in either :(

Comment: yes, i think you use servlet, if not try to replace `output.close();` to `output.flush();` this is for documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#flush%28%29

Comment: thanks, at least I know exactly what I am creating, so I can expand my "googling" :) Will try that asap

Comment: As weird as it is, I do 
    output.writeChars("some random text");
    System.out.println(output.size());
    output.flush();
    System.out.println(output.size());
    output.close();
    System.out.println(output.size());
and I do expect the size to go to 0 after flushing, but it still remains the same for all 3 printouts :O

Comment: i have idea how if you use httpservlet response ..? this is for ample http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/HelloWorld.shtml

Comment: Yeah I guess I have no other choice. Will install TomCat now. Thanks